# AngularJS - Bypass the $http promises object managment

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-service

I've a service like this:

```
angular.module('module')
.factory('UserList', function ($http) {
    return {
        getUserList: $http.get('/portal-services/NemesysPortalBackend/rest/user/all')
    };
 });
```

this constraint me to do

```
UserList.getUserList.then(function(res){$scope.data = res.data;})
```

in every controller where I need it.
Is there any way to "facade" it to simply have

```
$scope.data = UserList.getUserList();
```

Thanks

Comment: The reason you have to call it like that is because the call is made asynchronously. Even if you could, I don't think you want to hack this into something that blocks.

Comment: `$http` used to allow for "unwrapping" promises when assigning directly to a `$scope` object, but this was removed in 1.3. You can still do what you want if you use `$resource`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption here that the user list doesn't change often, so this way you can cache it to a variable... otherwise you will need to make a call each time you expect the list changes (or reload the list using an interval?)

Fetching data before it's really needed is called "Eager loading"

```
angular.module('module').factory('UserList', function ($http, $q, $interval) { // import $q as well
    var userList = []; // initialized as blank array

    var refreshList = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/portal-services/NemesysPortalBackend/rest/user/all').then(
            function(successResponse){
                userList = successResponse.data;
                deferred.resolve(successResponse);
            },function(failureResponse){
                // do something on error?
                deferred.reject(failureResponse);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    } 
    refreshList(); // eager load, run right away

    // i don't recommend this next line, there are better ways of doing this
    $interval(refreshList(), 1000*60); // get new list every 60 seconds


    return {
        getUserList: function(){ return userList; }, // return user list only
        refreshList: function(){ refreshList(); } // return promise which getting new list
    };
 });
```

Again, I don't recommend using $interval to reload the list, but instead call refreshList any time updates are made to the user list

Ex:

```
angular.module('module').controller('userCtrl', function(UserList) { 
    $scope.data = UserList.getUserList();

    // once you change the user list, call a refresh
    UserList.addUser().then(UserList.refreshList()).then(function(){
         $scope.data = UserList.getUserList();
    );



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because JavaScript is single-threaded. This means, that when you use some call that is asynchronous, you cannot ever make it synchronous. There is no waiting(*) in Javascript. You cannot block your function call to wait for the results from the server.

Even if you tried as hard as this:

```
function getResult() {
   var result;
   UserList.getUserList.then(function(res) {
       result = res.data; // this should break the loop below
   });
   while (!result) {}; // active waiting, wasting CPU cycles
   return result;
}
```

...it wouldn't work because the callback function will not be executed until the currently running code (i.e., the infinite loop) finishes. An infinite loop like this would freeze the whole application forever.

---

(*) this doesn't mean that you cannot schedule functions to be called at some point later. Promises and closures help a lot with it.